# Prestashop proper way to load login and signup on fancybox iframe pop-up

Tags: php, prestashop, fancybox-2, prestashop-1.6

I want to load **authentication.tpl** on a fancybox iframe without the header and footer.

I know that appending to the url `content_only=1` works on certain pages

( for instance on CMS pages )

I tried:

*A* - **blockuserinfo** module **nav.tpl** template file

```
        <a class="login" href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Log in to your customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}">
        {l s='Sign in' mod='blockuserinfo'}
        </a>
```

then on the **global.js** i have the function calling fancybox

```
// Login Box
$(document).on('click', '.login', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    if (!!$.prototype.fancybox)
        $.fancybox({
            'padding':  0,
            'width':    1087,
            'height':   610,
            'type':     'iframe',
            'href':     url + 'content_only=1'
        });
});
```

the `url` var output in console is as expected

`http://localhost/myprestshop/my-account?content_only=1`

*B* - I also tried setting in **AuthController.php**

```
$this->content_only = true;
```

but in **my-account** page the smarty variable `content_only` is still set to `0`

what is the proper way to accomplish that on prestashop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to have a login pop up show in a fancybox iframe without header and footer

just call `authentication` instead of `my-account`

```
    <a class="login" href="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Log in to your customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}">
        {l s='Sign in' mod='blockuserinfo'}
    </a>
```

and then use the javascript function to attach the click handler to it as I did on my OP.